# How to use custom cursor?

Tags: cursor

I just switched to ubuntu from Windows and I had made a custom cursor for myself on windows and I'm trying to use that same one on ubuntu. All I can find is something about a cursor theme, but not where I can just put the individual cursor image. @.@;

Cursor I'm trying to use: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmaxlumwxq58bmn/normal.ani

Thank you.

Comment: Cursors work different in Linux. You'll have to either port your theme or find a cursor theme for Linux.

Comment: How would one go about porting my theme? Is there any simple converter tool to make my windows cursors work for linux then? Thanks for your time.